# save pptx as pdf through excel

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint, save-as

I am trying to convert all pptx files in a give path to pdf files.

my code:

```
Sub pptxtopdf()

    Dim ppt As Object
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object


    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Set ppt = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If ppt Is Nothing Then
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("P:\Operations\Data & Deliverables\Projects\Amica\presentation_workspace\1_ spring 2015\Presentations\Volvo")
    i = 1
    'loops through each file in the directory 
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        Set WDReport = ppt.Presentations.Open(objFile.Path)

        Dim FileName2 As String
        FileName2 = Replace(objFile.Path, "pptx", "pdf")

        'WDReport.ExportAsFixedFormat FileName2, ppFixedFormatTypePDF
        WDReport.SaveAs FileName2, ppSaveAsPDF

        WDReport.Close
        ppt.Quit

        Set ppt = Nothing
        Set WDReport = Nothing


        i = i + 1
    Next objFile


End Sub
```

error msg

```
Presentation.SaveAs :  Invalid enumeration value.
```

Cannot see what I'm doing wrong?

same problem as here but the solution didnt work for me - [Excel macro to save pptx as pdf; error with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756140/excel-macro-to-save-pptx-as-pdf-error-with-code)

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are late binding `PowerPoint.Application` so its enumeration values are not exposed or available in the global VBA namespace.

As you have not added `option explicit` to warn you of undeclared variables your use of the undeclared `ppSaveAsPDF` causes no error but has no value.

Add:

```
const ppSaveAsPDF as long = 32
```

To the top of the module to provide the expected value to `SaveAs`.

Comment: Ahhhh right I see. Thanks a lot. Was driving me crazy.